# In java programme, How to know the stored procudure running right or raise some error?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jdbc

In Oracle/MySQL stored procedure, It cannot return a value to the caller, we have to use syntax like this:

```
call SOME_STORED_PROCEDURE();
```

So, How the jdbc/java know the procedure going right or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if something goes wrong, the procedure would raise an exception. So if the procedure returns without exceptions, it was OK.

Comment: how to handle stored procedure exception in jdbc/java ?

Comment: I am not a Java programmer but I assume similar to regular SQL. Try ... catch ... ?

Comment: so, the exception inside the stored procedure will raise out to the api layer? then, I got it! I'll make a try, thank you!